# Redirect URL (including port) with params using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect from

```
http://www.example.com:81/my/api/search?query=test
```

to

```
http://www.example.com:81/my/php/api.php?query=test
```

using

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^api/search(.*)$ /php/api.php?%1 [L]
```

However, it doesn't work for me. Additionaly for testing htaccess rules I use http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Possibly even better would be to check if request starts from ^api and it's GET type (I guess using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}`) then redirect to /my/php/api.php?[query params here]

Anyone can point me into right direction?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/4790490

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: My .htaccess is located at the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess is located in `/my/` directory then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=.
RewriteRule ^api/search/?$ php/api.php [L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be automatically carried over to target URL.